# How can i list all partitions available on a Flash SPI ESP32 microcontroller

Tags: c++, esp32, arduino-c++, arduino-esp32, flash-memory

I have an ESP32 pcb electronics and I need to list all partitions the onboard SPI Flash has.

I've googled it however I could not find it to this date.

Comment: IIRC one of the standard ESP32 examples includes code for this.

Comment: well, it took me forever to find the code below... so here it is

Answer (score 0):

To list all partitions setup in a flash SPI IC one can use the following functions:

```
    void partition_info(){
        Serial.println("Partition list:");
        partloop(ESP_PARTITION_TYPE_APP);
        partloop(ESP_PARTITION_TYPE_DATA);
    }
    
    void partloop(esp_partition_type_t part_type) {
      esp_partition_iterator_t iterator = NULL;
      const esp_partition_t *next_partition = NULL;
      iterator = esp_partition_find(part_type, ESP_PARTITION_SUBTYPE_ANY, NULL);
      while (iterator) {
         next_partition = esp_partition_get(iterator);
         if (next_partition != NULL) {
            Serial.printf("partition addr: 0x%06x; size: 0x%06x; label: %s\n", next_partition->address, next_partition->size, next_partition->label);  
         iterator = esp_partition_next(iterator);
        }
      }

}
```